# In Django views how can I itirate form fields

Tags: python, django

In Django views I can iterate over files posted by a form

```
def stack_register(request):
"""
"""

print(request)
print('type request: ', type(request))


if request.method == 'POST':

    for key in request.FILES.keys():
        print('key: ' + key)


return HttpResponse('received')
```

How can I do the same for the other form fields?

Comment: Have you tried reading the [documentation for the `request` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/)?

Comment: I have re-read it and the documentation says one can get a Querydict object by request.POST and get the keys by using the items() function. I had tried this but got an exception trying to print it. It is also tricky to pull out the value since it is a tuple. As for having to read idiosyncratic documentation for every small detail this is a not so pleasant time and effort consuming feature of python and django the so called type indifference is just a sham

Comment: So you believe that other people invest "unpleasant" time and effort into educating themselves just so that you don't have to? Learning things _does_ take time and effort; whether it is "unpleasant" is mostly up to the learner. Learning how to _learn_ things seems even harder.

Comment: No I believe that sharing info as I do often is the aim of this site and that shortcuts are good practice when at hand if you don't want to answer go somewhere else.

Comment: No, the aim of this site is for people to help each other with _programming_ problems they can't resolve themselves. Not wanting to read the documentation yourself is neither a programming problem, nor one that you can't resolve, and certainly not something we can help you with.

Comment: Django is a programing problem which is solvable albeit not interesting. I just spent 2 hours deciphering the idiosyncratic documentation in a language I learned last week which was unnecessary and silly and another 30 minutes pondering the inhospitable natives.

Comment: If you are new to python in general, that is probably the problem here. You should familiarize yourself a bit more with the language, for example by reading code written by others. I have no clue about django, but if you have the information in a dict, it's perfectly easy to process: to iterate over all keys in a dict, simply do `for key in mydict:` and then access the values with `mydict[key]`. And btw, this is something that every good python introduction should demonstrate - maybe rethink your approach to learning python.

Comment: It is not a regular dict it is a Querydict and needs keys for deserialization I was hoping to see if the form data was coming through which is not that simple when you don't know if the client side in JQuery is working or not

Comment: It took me less than 10 seconds to google "Querydict" and, by reading the official documentation, get the information that "QueryDict implements all the standard dictionary methods, because it’s a subclass of dictionary" - which means you can still iterate over it like you would with a normal dictionary (that's what subclassing stuff is all about, reusing functionality). So the approach I described above should work.

Comment: Your `request.FILES` example code works just fine with the `request.GET` and `request.POST` `QueryDict`s. You have apparently not given it a try before asking.

Comment: Django has the best documentation I have ever seen. It's clear and understandable, and contains thorough examples for every situation and every part of development on an app. I have no idea what you're complaining about

Comment: my my your a bunch of local patriots defending the motherland and its beautiful landscape. still none of your bloated documents provided my week java, js, jquery mind with a simple list of keys. check out my answer before you spend another 10 seconds googling your condescending long-winded tutorials and documents. A queryDict is a tuple wich of which idiosyncratically the first value is the key and the others serve as either as a single value or a list of values. This is ugly coding.

Comment: I wonder if this preference of arcana over logic and architecture is distinctive to python, Django or overly board stackoverflow hecklers?

Comment: @RubberDuck sorry, lost you there. I have no idea what you're talking about anymore...

Comment: I'm talking about processing a submitted form into a python tuple instead of a dictionary with keys and values.

Comment: one could alternate values between single and list

Comment: Yall remind me of a teacher I once had who tried to insalt a girl in my class for asking hat he called a lazy question. I reminded him of Arthur C. Clarke who said that a teacher that can be replaced by a machine should be

Answer (score -1):

The field information may be obtained by printing tuples in the request but to my best knowledge getting the values necessitates actually reading them or prior knowledge of the keys.

This is how I got it:

```
def stack_register(request):
"""
"""

print(request)
print('type request: ', type(request))


if request.method == 'POST':

    print('')

    for key in request.FILES.keys():
        print('key: ' + key)
        print('file_name: ' + str(request.FILES[key]))


    print('type', type(request.POST.items()))


    for tuple in request.POST.items():  #this was the probelmatic code
        print('tuple: ' + str(tuple))

    #keep syntax for list
    #library = request.POST.getlist('library')
    #print('library: ', library)

    library = request.POST.__getitem__('library')
    print('library: ', library)

    stack = request.POST.__getitem__('stack')
    print('stack: ', stack)

    time = request.POST.__getitem__('time')
    print('time: ', time)

    medium = request.POST.__getitem__('medium')
    print('medium: ', medium)

    comments = request.POST.__getitem__('comments')
    print('comments: ', comments)

    storage = request.POST.__getitem__('storage')
    print('storage: ', storage)   


return HttpResponse('received')
```

In my book this is much easier and offers more hands-on control than learning the wily ways of Django forms, their long and tedious documentation.

By the way to all document buffs I think the best documentation for code is well written simple articulate code.

Comment: Why would you use `items()`? That makes no sense here and will _not_ give you the keys, but a list of `(key, value)` tuples. Simply doing `for key in request.POST:`, as I said in my comment on the question, should iterate over all keys. Also, you should not use `__getitem__`, simply do `request.POST['time']` or generalized `mydict[key]`. Please read http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries as you seem to be very confused about how to use a dictionary.

Comment: `request.POST.keys()` returns the keys in the `POST` `QueryDict`, exactly the same as with `request.FILES.keys()`. no prior knowledge of the keys is needed at all.

Comment: You are correct on the tuple remark but when iterating over the POST keys I didn't obtain the information and didn't find the keys so printing the tuple gave me human readable info.

Comment: It would seem I have trespassed on lanzz private territory. It would seem he aims to educate me in the ways of code, python, django and the world. shame this scholar and wise educator has his facts wrong. request.POST.keys() does not yield the field keys and lanzz yields not but contempt

Comment: @RubberDuck besides the fact that lanzz is correct, you might want to reconsider insulting the same people you expect to help you out

Comment: and I thought I was being cordial

Comment: I don't care if this lanzz or anyone else is the inventor of stack overflow or Django  once it is open source and free to all condescending educational remarks reflect on the poor character of their origin.